# Java pass \ in the input String - Java Graphql Json

Tags: java, string, graphql, aws-appsync

I have a mutation query to be passed to aappsync graphql query as shown below which should be passed from Java client code

```
{
    "query": "mutation UpdateUser{setUserInformationAdmin(information: {UserName:\"testUser20SK\",Email:\"testUser20SK@lb.de\",Enabled:true,SecurityHintEnabled:true,Api:\"Default\"})}",
    "variables": null,
    "operationsName": null
}
```

The problem here is the input strings should be in the format \"testUser20SK\" when passing to the query.

But when I give the input in the format for example:

```
queryBuilder.append("{\"query\":\"mutation UpdateUser{setUser(information: {UserName:\""+userInformation.getUserName()+"\"");
```

it sends the input as `UserName:"testUser20SK"`

The query is working only when input is passed as UserName:\"testUser20SK\"

Is there a way to pass input in the format UserName:\"testUser20SK\"  in Java code instead of UserName:"testUser20SK".

While writing this questipn itself I had struggled because the  \ was not displaying properly.

Comment: Put three backslashes before the quote instead of just one. A double backslash translates to a backslash, and the third backslash is the one you already have, which quotes the quotes.

Comment: Yes. works. Actually I am trying it for past 5 hours but it worked only after I posted the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the input in the format worked for me

```
 queryBuilder.append("{\"query\":\"mutation UpdateUser{setUserInformation(information: {UserName:\\\""+userInformation.getUserName()+"\\\"");
```